# How do I use this for-loop to this webscraping stock module?

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I have a little problem that I don't get it about this for-loop

I have a list of stocksymbols

```
Stocks = ['ADVANC.BK', 'AOT.BK', 'AWC.BK', 'BAM.BK', 'BBL.BK', 'BDMS.BK', 'BEM.BK', 'BGRIM.BK']
```

and I use module `parinya` to get the data of the stock price
e.g.

```
data = parinya.getHistStock('ADVANC.BK, interval='1d', day_begin='01-01-2018', day_end='10-01-2018')
print(data)


Output >>
              Open   High    Low  Close   Adj Close      Volume
Date                                                          
2018-01-03  191.5  197.5  191.0  196.5  176.633011  15405400.0
2018-01-04  196.5  197.0  194.0  194.0  174.385773   8361700.0
2018-01-05  195.0  197.0  194.5  195.0  175.284637  10294800.0
2018-01-08  195.0  197.0  194.5  196.0  176.183548   8141500.0
```

so I decide to use `for-loop` to get all of the data

```
Data_all_stock = []
for stock in Stocks:
    data = parinya.getHistStock(stock, interval='1d', day_begin='01-01-2018', day_end='10-01-2018')
    Data_all_stock.append(data)

print(Data_all_stock)
```

and this error occurs

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/parinya/stock.py in getHistStock(stock, interval, day_begin, day_end)
     89             data = website.text.split('\n')[:-1]
     90             data = [d.split(',') for d in data]
---> 91             col = data[0]
     92             #print(col)
     93     data = pd.DataFrame(data[1:])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I also try this

```
Data_all_stock = []
for stock in Stocks:
    data = parinya.getHistStock(f"'{stock}'", interval='1d', day_begin='01-01-2018', day_end='10-01-2018')
    Data_all_stock.append(data)

print(Data_all_stock)
```

and it's still erros

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/parinya/stock.py in _get_crumbs_and_cookies(stock)
     68         crumb = re.findall('"CrumbStore":{"crumb":"(.+?)"}', str(soup))
     69 
---> 70         return (header, crumb[0], website.cookies)
     71 
     72 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

so, I decided to look at module parinya and this is the stock.py look like :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import string
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime
import pandas as pd
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

def getSETSymbols(sector = 'ALL'):
    if sector == 'ALL':
        symbols = []
        url = 'https://www.set.or.th/set/commonslookup.do?language=th&country=TH&prefix={{key}}'
        key = ['NUMBER']
        key.extend(list(string.ascii_uppercase))
        for k in key:
            r = requests.get(url.replace('{{key}}',k), verify=False)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
            for i in soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('.*companyprofile.*')):
                symbols.append(i.text)
        return symbols

    symbols = []
    url = 'https://marketdata.set.or.th/mkt/sectorquotation.do?sector=SET100&language=th&country=TH'
    if sector != 'SET100':
        url = url.replace('SET100', sector)
    r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    for i in soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('.*symbol.*')):
        symbols.append(i.text.strip())
    return symbols

def getSET100Price():
    url = 'https://marketdata.set.or.th/mkt/sectorquotation.do?sector=SET100&language=th&country=TH'
    r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    for i in soup.findAll('caption'):
        timestamp = i.text
        timestamp = timestamp[timestamp.find('ข้อมูลล่าสุด'):].split()
        temp = timestamp[1].split('/')
        temp = temp[0] + '-' + temp[1] + '-' + str(int(temp[2]) - 543)
        timestamp = datetime.strptime(temp + ' ' + timestamp[2], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

    data = []
    for i in soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('.*symbol.*')):
        children = i.parent.parent.findChildren("td", recursive=False)
        symbol = i.text.strip()
        price = float(children[9].text)
        data.append((symbol, price))

    return data, timestamp

def _get_crumbs_and_cookies(stock):
    url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}/history'.format(stock)
    with requests.session():
        header = {'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                  'Expires': '-1',
                  'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
                  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) \
                   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36'
                  }

        website = requests.get(url, headers=header, verify=False)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(website.text, 'lxml')
        crumb = re.findall('"CrumbStore":{"crumb":"(.+?)"}', str(soup))

        return (header, crumb[0], website.cookies)


def convert_to_unix(date):
    datum = datetime.strptime(date, '%d-%m-%Y')
    return int(mktime(datum.timetuple()))


def getHistStock(stock, interval='1d', day_begin='01-03-2018', day_end='28-03-2018'):
    day_begin_unix = convert_to_unix(day_begin)
    day_end_unix = convert_to_unix(day_end)
    col = [1]
    while len(col)==1:
        header, crumb, cookies = _get_crumbs_and_cookies(stock)
        with requests.session():
            url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/' \
                  '{stock}?period1={day_begin}&period2={day_end}&interval={interval}&events=history&crumb={crumb}' \
                .format(stock=stock, day_begin=day_begin_unix, day_end=day_end_unix, interval=interval, crumb=crumb)
            website = requests.get(url, headers=header, cookies=cookies, verify=False)
            data = website.text.split('\n')[:-1]
            data = [d.split(',') for d in data]
            col = data[0]
            #print(col)
    data = pd.DataFrame(data[1:])
    data.columns = col
    data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
    return data.apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='float', errors='coerce')

def getLivePrice(stock):
    return si.get_live_price(stock)
```

Answer (score 1):

---

**Cause:**

My suspicion is that `getHistStock` does not have adequate error handling for invalid date selections. I suspect that your current selected dates of `day_begin='01-01-2018', day_end='10-01-2018'` are outside of valid periods for returning data, in the expected form, for at least some of your tickers; this is leading to your errors.

If I go to [finance.yahoo.com](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AWC.BK/history?p=AWC.BK) and look up that period, for each of your tickers, by the time I reach `AWC.BK`, I am seeing the website display `Date shouldn't be prior to '2019-10-10'` - a [quick check for the IPO date](https://www.set.or.th/set/factsheet.do?symbol=AWC&ssoPageId=3&language=en&country=US) gives me `'10/10/2019'` as the float/listed date i.e. the first date for which there would be data. You can repeat this for [`BAM.BK`](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BAM.BK/history?p=BAM.BK),  `Date shouldn't be prior to '2019-12-16'` ,  [`Listed Date 16/12/2019`](https://www.set.or.th/set/factsheet.do?symbol=BAM&ssoPageId=3&language=en&country=US).

***Disclaimer:*** You can use the [IPO](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/ipo.asp) checker of your choice. I know nothing about Stocks so simply used the factsheets from https://www.set.or.th/ to check the dates yahoo finance was indicating.

---

**Possible fix:**

At its most basic - You could add a `try except` error wrapper within your loop `for stock in Stocks:` ; handle the error as you see fit e.g. add a 'No data' list entry in the `except` then continue looping.

Of course, you can also check the IPO dates for each of your tickers in advance, and adjust your requested ranges accordingly, but you likely still need error handling as good practice for unexpected results.

---

**Test cases for hypothesis: (**not tested**)**

Expected fail -

```
data = parinya.getHistStock('AWC.BK', interval='1d', day_begin='01-01-2018', day_end='10-01-2018')
print(data)
```

Expected pass -

```
data = parinya.getHistStock('AWC.BK', interval='1d', day_begin='10-10-2019', day_end='20-10-2019')
print(data)
```

---